# Enumerating matrices function of ranks

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Is there an expression/approximate expression for number of real matrices $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of rank $r\leq n$?

Is it known if $M$ is restricted to symmetric/skew-symmetric matrices?

Does sequence in https://oeis.org/A064230 work?

Comment: See Zivkovic's 2005 arxiv print on classification of small binary matrices.  The table inside goes up to n=8, I believe.

Comment: any asymptotic expression?

Comment: I don't recall.  If there is one in the paper it is likely conjectural.

Comment: The probability that a random $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix is singular is equal to the probability that a random $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ $(1,-1)$-matrix is singular (by a simple argument). For the status of this difficult problem, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411095v3.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley So even status of enumerating singular matrices asymptotically is done only recently. So at this point asking to enumerate approximate number of rank $r$ matrices is probably expected to face difficulty?

Comment: @Turbo: The Tao-Vu paper only gives improved bounds. It is still quite far from an asymptotic determination. See Conjecture 1.3, which is still open. Perhaps there is an analogue of Conjecture 1.3 for rank $r$. See also http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501313.pdf.

Comment: you mean conjecture $1.4? http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411095v3.pdf

Comment: Oops, yes, Conjecture 1.4.

Comment: Does this work? https://oeis.org/A064230

Answer (score 3):

This is not your question, but it is related and gives an upper bound: Over $\mathbb{F}_2$, there is a quite explicit formula for the number of matrices of rank $r.$ See [this paper of Blake and Studholme (2006).](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cvs/coding/random_report.pdf) (they actually cite van Lint and Wilson's combinatorics book, so that may be a better reference).

Comment: I am looking over reals though.